# Do routers and networks have have a "max threads" configuration?

Tags: cisco, router, testing

I've been stress testing my application now and I've identified a high average network connection time. This is odd because I haven't gone over the max bandwith at all.

What can this be caused by? Have I gone over the "max thread limit" on the router/network if there is such a thing?

I am not good at networking at all so all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should provide more detailed information on what you are testing and what the observed behaviour is.

Answer (score 2):

You may be confused about something. You application may create threads for execution on your PC, but routers switch packets one at a time, regardless of what came before, and routers have no expectation that anything is coming in the future. Each packet is handled as an individual packet to be switched.

The router may not be able to handle the throughput at wire speed, but it doesn't spawn threads to handle your individual traffic flows. It has to deal with serialization, buffers, routing table lookups, etc. which can overwhelm it when it starts receiving more traffic than it can handle.

Comment: There's a finite number of connections any NAT or firewall can track. (that can be a very low number for numerous Bad Routers(tm))

Comment: @RickyBeam, I understand that, but it is a router table sort of problem, nothing to do with threads spawned on a router. My point was that there is confusion about threads, and that the router doesn't spawn threads for connections the was the traffic generator may.

Comment: We don't know what the application is doing -- or for that matter, what router is involved. If it's opening and closing lots of connections, if could be flooding the connection tracking tables, triggering a firewall rule, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say to give you a definitive answer.

A router is like a computer. If you throw a big workload at a cheap, home grade one you're likely to hit its limits. However, if you use a suitably sized one it will have no issues doing what you need.

In other words although your router doesn't seem to be able to handle your applications load it does not mean that everyone else's router would struggle too.